# Auto-filling when adding new value in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am trying to set up QGIS to work on gathering bird data. I have my attributes set up so that the common name, Latin name, quantity, date and other information is recorded.

Is there a way to get the fields to always autofill with what I want I.E Common name is always blue tit rather than me filling it in each time?

Is there an easy way for me to export the fields to other layers that I can then modify to have a different species name rather than redoing the process for each layer?

Comment: Adde an answer how to set a default value for fields. However, I don't understand what you mean by "export the fields to other layers". What exactly do you want to do? You have the same features, but you want to have them with different names? Or you want to create several (empty) layers with different default values? Are you aware of the field calculator and what you can do with it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6):

Right click the layer in the layer panel to go to `Layer properties / Tab Attributes Form` and select the field for which you want to set a default value. On the right side under `Default`, you can set `Default value` and make other settings:

[image]

Comment: In addition, the widget type can be changed to "categorized", so one doesn't even have to type a name at all, but can select from a predefined list with the most prominent species of a survey area.